# Mysql Import: ERROR at line 7055: Unknown command '\n'. Operation failed with exitcode 1

Tags: mysql

I'm encountering a problem when I am importing my 3GB database backup with .sql file extension to MySQL.  I already tried to import it using command prompt and MySQL workbench but both are not successful.  How can I solve this issue?

Comment: how did you make the backup? Plesk?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @Progman ERROR at line 7055: Unknown command '\n'. Operation failed with exitcode 1

Comment: @WilliamJones Please edit your question to include the code or commands in the command line how you try to load the backup into mysql. Also edit your question to include the section around line `7055` of your sql file. Also provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question, specially with a minimal SQL file, which can be tested by others which shows the error message you got.